# asp.net session expires before the time limit

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables

I Have asp.net application in which i am using open id of google for authentication and i used to display the email address returned from google on a label control like this in vb.net

```
lblemail.Text = Session("U_EMAIL").ToString()
```

Problem is that after some time this error displays and i have to re login and then page works normaly error is `Obeject Reference is not Set To an Instance of Object` on this line
`lblemail.Text = Session("U_EMAIL").ToString()`

I tried to increase the limit of session in web.config like

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId ="true" timeout="129600" />
```

But Still No Difference because when page loads and after some time the above error displayed please help me to remove this error

Comment: Check null for session.`if(Session("U_EMAIL")!= null)` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There maybe is other things that happens to your website. Is it in dev? You maybe restart the webserver. The *Application pool* get's restarted if you change many files in your websites folder, or if you touch anything in the bin directory.

Comment: I Also Incresed the time Limit of `Session State` in IIS and then Restarted the IIS But Still no effect after some time the error shows and i have to relogin

Comment: Do a nullcheck and redirect to login page if it's null. There is some other things that happens on your website that force the session to be removed. Hard to tell why :/